# Get object keys for filtered values

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

The case is simple - I've got a following object:

```
Object {1: false, 2: true, 3: false, 4: false, 5: false, 6: false, 7: false, 8: true, 12: false, 13: false, 14: false, 15: false, 16: false, 17: false, 18: false, 19: false}
```

and I need to get an array of ids that had true value, using underscore. In above case that would be:

```
[2, 8]
```

I tried few things but I'm a bit stuck. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
var keys = [];
_.each( obj, function( val, key ) {
  if ( val ) {
    keys.push(key);
  }
});
```

*There may be easier/shorter ways using plain Underscore.*

---

In case anyone here uses [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) instead of Underscore, the following is also possible, which is *very short* and *easy to read*:

```
var keys = _.invert(obj, true)[ "true" ];
```

Comment: pure javascript (without underscore) is the same long. I was hoping that there's a method that I missed in the docs...

Comment: yeah, probably there isn't any shorter way.

Comment: There is no method in underscore, but you can easily provide one by using _.extend. Look at my response : you can find first or all keys, and use a function as criteria.

Answer (score 9):

Giorgi Kandelaki gave a good answer, but it had some potential problems (see my comment on his answer).

The correct way is:

```
_(obj).pairs().filter(_.last).map(_.first)
```

or

```
_.map(_.filter(_.pairs(obj),_.last),_.first)
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. The second line of code to be precise. Just replace `_.last` with the iterator function of your choice and voilà! You have a statement equivalent of yet non-existent underscore method `_.findAllKeys`.

Answer (score 8):

```
var data = {1: false, 2: true, 3: false, 4: true};

var filteredIds = _.filter(_.keys(data), function (key) {
    return data[key];
});

// result [2, 4]


var rejectedIds = _.reject(_.keys(data), function (key) {
    return data[key];
});

// result [1, 3]
```

Comment: oh, that's a nice one!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `_.pick`. Like this:

```
var data = {1: false, 2: true, 3: false, 4: false, 5: false, 6: false, 7: false, 8: true, 12: false, 13: false, 14: false, 15: false, 16: false, 17: false, 18: false, 19: false}

var keys = _.keys(_.pick(data, function(value) {
  return value;
}));
```

Comment: This solution does not work.  Change out data for `[{a: true}, {b: false}, {c: true}, {d: false}]` and you will get `["0", "1", "2", "3"]`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
_.pairs(obj)
 .filter(function(pair) { return pair[1] })
 .map(function(pair) { return pair[0] })
```

Or the same but bit more concise:

```
_.pairs(obj).filter(_.last).map(_.first)
```

Comment: There are some problems with your code:
both pairs() and filter() return an array, NOT an underscore object, so when calling filter() or map() on that result, you're invoking them on a native array object. That works in modern browsers, but will fail if the browser has no support for Array.filter or Array.map. See my answer for the correct way to do this.

Comment: Oh, nice finding. Thanks. I just gave a quick answer, not thinking a lot about browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it very easily

```
var obj = { a: false, b: false, c: true, d: false, e: true, f: false };
    name, names;

name = _.findKey(obj, true);
// -> 'c'
names = _.findKeys(obj, true);
// -> ['c', 'e']
```

For that you juste need to extend underscore a little :

```
_.mixin({

  findKey: function(obj, search, context) {
    var result,
        isFunction = _.isFunction(search);

    _.any(obj, function (value, key) {
      var match = isFunction ? search.call(context, value, key, obj) : (value === search);
      if (match) {
        result = key;
        return true;
      }
    });

    return result;
  },

  findKeys: function(obj, search, context) {
    var result = [],
        isFunction = _.isFunction(search);

    _.each(obj, function (value, key) {
      var match = isFunction ? search.call(context, value, key, obj) : (value === search);
      if (match) {
        result.push(key);
      }
    });

    return result;
  }
});
```

And you can even use a function as filter, like this :

```
var team = {
  place1: { name: 'john', age: 15 },
  place2: { name: 'tim', age: 21 },
  place3: { name: 'jamie', age: 31 },
  place4: { name: 'dave', age: 17 }}

// Determine the places of players who are major
var placeNames = _.findKeys(team, function(value) { return value.age >= 18; });
// -> ['place2', 'place3']
```

Enjoy ;-)

Comment: This is incredibly over complicated.

Comment: What is complicated ? Is it too long to write :
  name = _.findKey(obj, true);

Comment: Calling a function is not complicated. Extending underscore to do something that it can already do seems like a complication to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = {1: false, 2: true /*...*/};
```

you can use reduce:

```
_(obj).reduce(function(memo, val, key){
    if (val)
        memo.push(key);
    return memo;
}, []);
```

or chain map:

```
_(obj).chain().map(function(val, key){
    if (val)
        return key;
}).reject(_.isUndefined).value();
```

Answer (score 1):

My version:

```
var list = {
    1: false, 2: true, 3: false, 4: false,
    5: false, 6: false, 7: false, 8: true,
    12: false, 13: false, 14: false, 15: false,
    16: false, 17: false, 18: false, 19: false
};

_.chain(list).map(function(val, key) {
    return val ? parseInt(key) : undefined
}).reject(function(val) {
    return _.isUndefined(val);
}).value();
// returns [2,8]
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be easier

```
result = _.chain(obj)
    .map(function(value, key){
        return value?key:false;
    })
    .filter(function(v){
        return v
    })
    .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findKey(obj, value){
    var key;

    _.each(_.keys(obj), function(k){
      var v = obj[k];
      if (v === value){
        key = k;
      }
    });

    return key;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, `_.invert(myObject)` returns `Object {false: "19", true: "8"}` so it applies the last matching element. And this is not what I want.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't see your comment earlier. I checked it in jsfiddle, and then realized that. But this should work. Any issues with this version?

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution:

```
// Your example data
var data = {1: false, 2: true, 3: false, 4: false, 5: false, 6: false, 7: false, 8: true, 12: false, 13: false, 14: false, 15: false, 16: false, 17: false, 18: false, 19: false};

// Outputs the keys: ["2", "8"]
_.keys(_.transform(data, function(r, v, k) { v ? r[k] = 1 : null; }));

// Outputs the keys as integers: [2, 8]
_.map(_.keys(_.transform(data, function(r, v, k) { v ? r[k] = 1 : null; })), _.parseInt)
```

So basically:

1. Transform the original object to strip out the false-valued keys
2. Grab the list of keys from the transformed result
3. Convert the keys to ints if you need to

Comment: Beware, `transform` does exist in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs), but not in [underscore](http://underscorejs.org).

Answer (score 0):

I use this one: 
*Retrieve all keys with the same value from an object (not only an object with just boolean values) using `lodash`*

```
function allKeys(obj, value) {
  _.keys(_.pick(obj, function (v, k) { return v === value; }));
}
```

Example:

```
var o = {a: 3, b: 5, c: 3};
var desiredKeys = allKeys(o, 3);
// => [a, c]
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a way to do it **without using any libraries** in ES6

```
let z = {2: true, 3:false, 8:true, 9:false, 10: false}
Array.from(new Set(Object.keys(z).map(function(k){if(z[k]){return k}}))).filter(f=>f)
```

and out you get `[2, 8]`

Comment: alternatively without arrow functions `Array.from(new Set(Object.keys(z).map(function(k){if(z[k]){return k}}))).filter(function(f){if(f){return true}})`

Answer (score -5):

I Do not know `underscore.js`. But using normal JS, I have written the below code.

```
function myFunction()
{
var str="1: false; 2: true; 3: false; 4: false; 5: false; 6: false; 7: false; 9: true; 12: false";
var n=str.split(";");

for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++)
{
     if(n[i].search("true")!=-1){
     alert(n[i].slice(0,n[i].search(":")));
     }
}
```

Comment: this is really NOT what I'm looking for. I've got a plain object, not a string.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz can't you get the value from the object??

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. I'm looking for a short underscore solution, just like I wrote in the description.

Comment: Converting a true object to a string representation is like serializing it. One could of course use a JSON serializer for that first and then apply your solution. But, seriously. Why on earth convert the object to string and manipulate that? Working with the true representation is *way* better, maintenance friendly and sane. The question was also about an underscore solution, which this is not.