# JS - Get object key-value pairs for filtered values WITHOUT underscore

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with filtering object's values by true/false, just like in this topic [Get object keys for filtered values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987705/get-object-keys-for-filtered-values) but without underscore, meaning using exclusively plain JS. There are many more or less similar questions on StackOverflow, but unfortunately I failed to set a working approach.

For example, I have an object:

```
var anObject = {first_property: false, second_property: true, third_property: false, fourth_property: false, fifth_property: false, sixth_property: true, seventh_property: false, eight_property: nine-nth_property: false}
```

I need to get a new object, featuring exclusively truthy values, like:

```
var newObject = { second_property: true, sixth_property: true }
```

To filter, I wrote the following filter:

```
function isValid(value) {
    if (typeof value === "undefined" || value == null || value.length == 0 || value == false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Broke my head and spent a few hours trying different approach, however the result is unsatisfactory. How should I built the algorithm to do this, which custom/out-of-the-box functions is worth using here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't reassign `Object`, at least name the variable `object` ;-)

Comment: @Luca OK, renamed it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop over the key/value pairs and find out which are `true`. The solution works as follows:

1. Gets the key/value pairs from the object using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).
2. Iterates over the entries using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
3. In each iteration, checks if value is `true`. If so, then adds the key/value pair to the result.

```js
var obj = {
  first_property: false,
  second_property: true,
  third_property: false,
  fourth_property: false,
  fifth_property: false,
  sixth_property: true,
  seventh_property: false
};

var res = Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
    if (value) {
      result[key] = value;
    }

    return result;
  }, {})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this using `Object.entries()` or `Object.keys()`, different array methods, etc, but I figured I'd provide one. Filter the keys down to those where the value is `true`, and then add those keys to the `output`.

```js
var obj = {
  first_property: false,
  second_property: true,
  third_property: false,
  fourth_property: false,
  fifth_property: false,
  sixth_property: true,
  seventh_property: false
};

var output = {};

Object.keys(obj)                                  //Get all keys from the object ['first_property', 'second_property', ...]
    .filter((key) => obj[key])                    //Filter the list of keys down to only those where their value is true
    .forEach((key) => output[key] = obj[key]);    //For each key in our filtered list, add it to the output object

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you for it! New things popping up for me, will spend today's evening on your and 31piy solutions to grasp the concept.

Comment: Glad to have helped. A solution like 31piy's using a single `reduce` is going to outperform mine, being that mine requires two iterations. That said, I've added some comments to my code so you can get a clearer idea of what some of the code is doing.

Comment: Grateful for it! Will get back to this question tomorrow after I grasp the concept and implement the solution successfully

Comment: Asking this questions was very useful for me, a great deal of new things that I learned over yesterday's evening, thank you for that. Finally, I successfully implemented the solution proposed by 31piy, as you said, it looks like being the most streamlined approach. Still, thanks to all of you, you complemented my knowledge

Answer (score 2):

Also it is possible by reducing `Object.keys` array (without additional filtering):

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => 
  ((obj[key] ? acc[key] = obj[key] : null), acc)
, {});

// {second_property: true, sixth_property: true}
```

And a bit shorter version:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => (obj[key] && (acc[key] = obj[key]), acc), {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter ([`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) the truthy keys and create a new object ([`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) with those:

```js
var obj = {first_property: false,second_property: true,third_property: false,fourth_property: false,fifth_property: false,sixth_property: true,seventh_property: false};    

var result = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k]).reduce((a,k) => (a[k] = obj[k], a), {});

console.log(result);
```